# Recursively find all files newer than a given time

Tags: linux, bash

How can I list all files newer than a given time? I'm looking for a one-liner that I can run in Bash with standard Linux utilities.

I know how to list all files newer than a given file (`find . -newer FILE`), but in my case I have a Unix timestamp (e.g. `1312604568`) to compare them to, instead of a file.

Comment: As a computer programmer, I can say with confidence that using `find` to locate files based on various criteria is definitely part of my workflow. As such, this would fall into the category of "*software tools primarily used by programmers*" and should be reopened. Pretty please.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This is a bit circuitous because `touch` doesn't take a raw `time_t` value, but it should do the job pretty safely in a script.  (The `-r` option to `date` is present in MacOS X; I've not double-checked GNU.)  The 'time' variable could be avoided by writing the command substitution directly in the `touch` command line.

```
time=$(date -r 1312603983 '+%Y%m%d%H%M.%S')
marker=/tmp/marker.$$
trap "rm -f $marker; exit 1" 0 1 2 3 13 15
touch -t $time $marker
find . -type f -newer $marker
rm -f $marker
trap 0
```

Comment: I just wanted to remember how to find files newer than another file - `find . -type f -newer <file>` was exactly want I was looking for

Comment: What does the `trap` do?

Comment: @Stewart: The first trap ensures that if the script exits or is signalled with HUP, INT, QUIT, PIPE or TERM signals, the temporary file is removed, and the script exits with status 1 (which is 'not success', hence 'failure').  The second trap ensures that the original 'trap on exit' is cancelled so that the script exits successfully.  The first trap doesn't try to catch all possible signals; it just catches the ones most likely to be used.  Some signals (KILL, STOP) can't be caught at all.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler  So those trailing numbers are the signal IDs ?

Comment: @Stewart: Yes; you can use names like HUP if you prefer, and don't need to program for archaic shells.  When I learned, names were not an option, so I don't use them.  Besides, the numbers are more compact, and I type `trap` commands quite often in shell scripts that create temporary files.  Of course, that's mostly laziness, not a real measurable time saving.  I've never bothered to check whether all the shells I currently use support names because they all support the numbers.  The name for `0` is EXIT.

Comment: The answer below by @rsanden is actually a one-liner and omits all the complexity of creating a file as a timestamp.

Comment: @Marvin: yes, but it depends on GNU `find`, rather than POSIX [`find`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html) which still doesn't support `-newermt` (but does support `-newer`).  That's neither entirely relevant nor entirely irrelevant, but this will work in places where GNU `find` is not installed whereas the other answer won't.  I'm not i/c the accept status of my answer vs others.  Of course, POSIX [`date`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/date.html) doesn't support the `-r` option, so there are still is a lack of portability.

Comment: Reasonable points, although from a practical standpoint -newermt will be "found" on OSX, cygwin, and probably all linuxes...  So maybe 90+% of the unixy environments people encounter.

Comment: this `date -r` as mentioned is for MacOS or FreeBSD, for Linux users please replace it with: `date -d @1312603983 '+%Y%m%d%H%M.%S'`

Answer (score 207):

You can find every file what is created/modified in the last day, use this example:

```
find /directory -newermt $(date +%Y-%m-%d -d '1 day ago') -type f -print
```

for finding everything in the last week, use '1 week ago' or '7 day ago'
anything you want

Comment: Sadly `newerXY` is a relatively new extension, not available by default e.g. in CentOS 5.8

Comment: You don't need the date command as the argument to -newermt is treated as the `-d` argument to date.

Comment: On OSX Mountain Lion (man page indicates 2007 BSD?), it appears that `date` requires the format to be at the end, and the `-d` option is in fact the `-v` option, so the above command looks like `find /directory -newermt $(date -v-1d +%Y-%m-%d) -type f -print`

Comment: by testing I find that -newermt actually means 'same or newer' which is not what is suggested by the word 'newer': `echo hello >./foo.txt; find -maxdepth 1 -name foo.txt -newermt @$(stat -c%Y foo.txt)` returns `./foo.txt`. Whereas `echo hello >./foo.txt; find -maxdepth 1 -name foo.txt -newermt @$(( $(stat -c%Y foo.txt)+1 ))` does not return anything. This is with `find` from GNU findutils 4.4.2.

Comment: In fact, you don't need the `$(date ...)` part. `-newerXt` accepts anything that comes after the `-d` in a `date` command, so `-newermt '1 day ago'` works nicely.

Comment: Helpful!  I used this to create an alias to find week old files on my MacOS: ```alias weekold='find . -type f -newermt "$(date -j -v -7d)"'```

Comment: While `-newermt` accepts the same as `-d` of `date`, it does not yield the same result. `find . -newermt $(date +%Y-%m-%d -d '1 day ago') -type f | wc -l` yields `32` while `find . -newermt '1 day ago' -type f | wc -l` yields `8`.

Answer (score 64):

Maybe someone can use it. Find all files which were modified within a certain time frame recursively, just run:

```
find . -type f -newermt "2013-06-01" \! -newermt "2013-06-20"
```

**NOTE:**

the first date is included, the second date is excluded, so that commands like

```
find . -type f -newermt "2013-06-20" \! -newermt "2013-06-20"
```

always return `0`

Comment: Nice! 
I use the `-not` to negate `-newermt`: 
`find . -type f -not -newermt  "2017-10-01"`

Comment: @Stefan what would happen of The logical 'NOT would ne omitted from The find command?

Comment: Also remember you can redirect output to a file for later usage, like `find . -type f -newermt "2013-06-01" \! -newermt "2013-06-20" > output.txt`

Answer (score 35):

Assuming a modern release, `find -newermt` is powerful:

```
find -newermt '10 minutes ago' ## other units work too, see `Date input formats`
```

or, if you want to specify a [`time_t`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/time_t/) (seconds since [epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(computing))):

```
find -newermt @1568670245
```

---

For reference, `-newermt` is not directly listed in the man page for find.  Instead, it is shown as `-newerXY`, where `XY` are placeholders for `mt`.  Other replacements are legal, but not applicable for this solution.

From `man find -newerXY`:

> Time specifications are interpreted as for the argument to the -d option of GNU date.

So the following are equivalent to the initial example:

```
find -newermt "$(date '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S' -d '10 minutes ago')" ## long form using 'date'
find -newermt "@$(date +%s -d '10 minutes ago')" ## short form using 'date' -- notice '@'
```

The `date -d` (and `find -newermt`) arguments are quite flexible, but the documentation is obscure.  Here's one source that seems to be on point: [Date input formats](https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_node/Date-input-formats.html)

Comment: You can also do something like: `find -newermt '4:00pm yesterday'`

Answer (score 19):

Given a unix timestamp (seconds since epoch) of `1494500000`, do:

```
find . -type f -newermt "$(date '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S' -d @1494500000)"
```

To grep those files for "foo":

```
find . -type f -newermt "$(date '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S' -d @1494500000)" -exec grep -H 'foo' '{}' \;
```

Comment: This is a good answer and needs to be upvoted more. One comment though. the date format parameter should rather be:  find . -type f -newermt "$(date -d @1494500000) +'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'" and find . -type f -newermt "$(date -r 1494500000) +'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'" on MacOSX

Answer (score 5):

You can also do this without a marker file.

The %s format to date is seconds since the epoch.  find's -mmin flag takes an argument in minutes, so divide the difference in seconds by 60.  And the "-" in front of age means find files whose last modification is less than age.

```
time=1312603983
now=$(date +'%s')
((age = (now - time) / 60))
find . -type f -mmin -$age
```

With newer versions of gnu find you can use -newermt, which makes it trivial.

Answer (score 1):

It's another way. You can recursively find files newer than a given timestamp using `touch -d` and `find /dir -newer` commands.

For example, if you need find files newer than '1 June 2018 11:02', you can create a file with this creation date.

```sh
touch -d '1 June 2018 11:02' ref_timestamp
```

Then, you can use the file timestamp as reference in `find` command.

```sh
find /dir -newer ref_timestamp
```

Answer (score 0):

There is [PowerShell available on Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/install/installing-powershell-core-on-linux?view=powershell-7.1) for some time so I recommend to use that since it does not deal just with pure text but handles real objects and so avoids formatting and make the task much easier

```
ls -recurse | where lastwritetime -gt ((get-date).AddDays(-1))
```

Answer (score -1):

So there's another way (and it is portable to some extent_

```
(python <<EOF
import fnmatch
import os
import os.path as path
import time

matches = []
def find(dirname=None, newerThan=3*24*3600, olderThan=None):
    for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(dirname or '.'):
        for filename in fnmatch.filter(filenames, '*'):
            filepath = os.path.join(root, filename)
            matches.append(path)
            ts_now = time.time()
            newer = ts_now - path.getmtime(filepath) < newerThan
            older = ts_now - path.getmtime(filepath) > newerThan
            if newerThan and newer or olderThan and older: print filepath
    for dirname in dirnames:
        if dirname not in ['.', '..']:
            print 'dir:', dirname
            find(dirname)
find('.')
EOF
) | xargs -I '{}' echo found file modified within 3 days '{}'
```

Comment: Could you explain what the code is doing please ?