# Check directory daily for new files - linux bash script

Tags: linux, bash

I'd like to monitor a directory for new files daily using a linux bash script.

New files are added to the directory every 4 hours or so. So I'd like to at the end of the day process all the files.
By process I mean convert them to an alternative file type then pipe them to another folder once converted.

I've looked at `inotify` to monitor the directory but can't tell if you can make this a daily thing.

Using `inotify` I have got this code working in a sample script:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read line
do
        echo "close_write: $line"
done < <(inotifywait -mr -e close_write "/home/tmp/")
```

This does notify when new files are added and it is immediate.

I was considering using this and keeping track of the new files then processing them at all at once, at the end of the day.

I haven't done this before so I was hoping for some help.

Maybe something other than `inotify` will work better.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a daily  cron job: http://linux.die.net/man/1/crontab

Comment: One question - is there a way to identify only the new files added?

Comment: Use find command to find files newer then... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6964747/find-all-files-recursively-newer-than-given-time

Answer (score 1):

Definitely should look into using a cronjob.  Edit your cronfile and put this in:

```
0 0 * * * /path/to/script.sh
```

That means run your script at midnight everyday.  Then in your `script.sh`, all you would do is for all the files, "convert them to an alternative file type then pipe them to another folder once converted".

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

To collect the files by the end of day, just use find:

`find $DIR -daystart -mtime -1 -type f`

Then as others pointed out, set up a cron job to run your script.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Your cron job (see other answers on this page) should keep a list of the files you have already processed and then use `comm -3 processed-list all-list` to get the new files.
[man comm](http://linux.die.net/man/1/comm)

Its a better alternative to 
`awk 'FNR==NR{a[$0];next}!($0 in a)' processed-list all-list`

and probably more robust than using `find` since you record the ones that you have actually processed.